# Puzzling incompatible peer dependency during Angular update from 6 to 8

Tags: angular, dependency-management

Following the Angular update guide (https://update.angular.io/) I started with

```
$ ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

But that yielded this list of some incompatibilities:

```
Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
Package "@ngrx/router-store" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/router" (requires "^6.0.0" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
Package "ngrx-tslint-oftype" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "^2.8.3", would install "3.4.5").
Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "6.1.3" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
Package "@angular/material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
Package "@angular/material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0" (extended), would install "8.1.0").
```

I updated `codelyzer` to knock that off the list.
I then figured that I could change the command to remove a few more:

```
$ ng update @angular/cli @angular/core @ngrx/store @angular/material @angular/http
```

That left me with this puzzling result, puzzling because one of the two `@angular/http` incompatibilities is still present!

```
Package "ngrx-tslint-oftype" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "^2.8.3", would install "3.4.5").
Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "7.2.15", would install "8.1.0")
```

So I have two issues:

1. For ngrx-tslint-oftype, I looked into ways to override the package's dependency on the typescript version, but what I found so far--mainly `npm shrinkwrap`--seemed to have issues.
2. Why is @angular/http still a complaint and how do I fix it?

Note that I also tried `ng update --all` but that gave me some incompatibilities with other packages, not relevant to the Angular upgrade.

I am hesitant to add a `--force`; would much prefer to be able to fix things so that is not a necessity. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@angular/http` has been deprecated by Angular and is no longer in use (See [here](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#http)). You can make use of `@angular/common/http` instead (See [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http)). You will need to use the `HttpClient` class from the `HttpClientModule`

**app.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule
 ],
...
```

Wherever you want to use it

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

class MyService() {
    constructor(http: HttpClient) { }
...
```

As for the issue with `ngrx-tslint-oftype`. Try upgrading your typescript version to 3.

Comment: I suppose the error ("incompatible peer dependency") was a valid message, but it was not pointing me to the correct issue, so thank you! It's funny--some time ago my team had already moved from `@angular/http` to `@angular/common/http`, per the Angular instructions -- but the actual entry in package.json had not been removed! So that was all I needed... I believe I had tried upgrading typescript, but if I recall it needs to be updated with Angular. For now I will just remove `ngrx-tslint-oftype` then reinstall it after doing the Angular upgrade.

Comment: I can only say - same here :) Thanks!